# How do I remove a rewrite rule?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've added a rewrite rule with the following code, and now I need to remove it.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^events$', 'index.php?post_type=events', 'top');
```

My issue is not that the rule is not working.  It is that the rule is already added, and I want to get rid of it.  Does deleting the add_rewrite_rule() line of code and flushing the rules get rid of it?

Answer (score 6):

the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function will delete and regenerate the rewrite rules. you can also visit the permalinks settings page in admin and save, that triggers a flush as well.

Comment: Just as a side note - in case anyone is manually editing their .htaccess file themselves - saving the permalinks settings also seems to reset the .htaccess file too.  Not a big issue, just make sure you have a backup if needed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I still get redirected as per the rule added earlier.